# Closed-form expression for a sum of reciprocals of factorials

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, asymptotics

Is there a closed-form expression for the finite sum $$\sum_{s=1}^{2^{n-1}}\frac1{(s-1)!}$$ as a function of $n$?

Comment: As others have pointed out, this is the initial portion of the Taylor series for $e$.  The Taylor series theorem, which you can look up, includes an estimate of the total error contributed by the terms after the $i$th. Say this error is $\operatorname{err}(i)$.  Then your expression is equal to $e - \operatorname{err}(2^{n-1})$.

Comment: sure what is the function $err(i)$?

Comment: Look it up in Wikipedia.

Comment: do you have a link?

Comment: You say "asymptotically" but you don't seem to care actually about the asymptotic behavior; you want an exact (or nearly exact?) evaluation of the sum at an arbitrary finite $n$, which is quite a different thing.

Comment: asymptotically parametrized by $n$.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=taylor+series+error

Comment: Asymptotically, this sum behaves like a constant function--among other possibilities, few of which are even close to what you seem to want. If you care what the value is at any particular finite $n$ (say, at $n = 100$) then you want something a lot more specific than just asymptotic behavior.

Comment: @Turbo Based on your comments below, I've rewritten the question for clarity; please revert my changes in part or whole if they don't reflect your intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The Taylor series for $e^x$ is
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} x^k = 1 + x + \frac{1}{2!} x^2 + \cdots.$$

> I guess "is there a closed form expression" is the correct terminology

I'm not sure whether you consider these closed-form, but here are two expressions for $$\sum_{k = 0}^N \frac{1}{k!}$$ that don't explicitly involve a sum:

**Solution 1**
$$\sum_{k = 0}^N \frac{1}{k!} = \frac{\Gamma(N + 1, 1)}{\Gamma(N)},$$ where $\Gamma(a)$ is the usual [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), and $\Gamma(a, b)$ is the [Incomplete Gamma Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function)---I'm not sure how satisfactory this is, since this identity basically amounts to unwinding definitions.

**Solution 2**
$$\sum_{k = 0}^N \frac{1}{k!} = \frac{1}{N!} \lfloor N! e \rfloor, \qquad N > 0;$$ this uses the fact that, after the zeroth, each $N$th partial sum of the series $\sum \frac{1}{k!}$ is largest multiple of $\frac{1}{N!}$ smaller than $e$, which is itself an easy consequence of the form of that series (and of course, that $e$ is its limit).

Taking $N = 2^{n - 1} - 1$ and reindexing gives expressions for your own sum.

Comment: What do you mean, i.e., what is the dependence of *what* on $k$?

Comment: By asymptotically, do you mean you want a good upper bound on the difference between your finite sum and the limiting value $e$?

Comment: Yes. Can we be precise?

Comment: Sure, the difference between the given sum and its limit $e$ is bounded in absolute value, e.g., by $\frac{2}{(2^n)!}$, which approaches zero *very* quickly with $n$. By precise, do you just mean, is there a closed-form expression for the given finite sum?

Comment: Say error is $e(n)$ and we have $0< e_l(n,1)< e_l(n,2)<\dots e(n)<\dots <e_u(n,2) < e_u(n,1)<\frac{2}{2^n!}$ where $\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty} e_l(u,i)=\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty} e_u(n,i)=e(n)$. Can we get the sequence of functions $e_l(n,i)$ and $e_u(n,i)$?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Could you be more precise?

Comment: I guess "is there a closed form expression" is the correct terminology.

Comment: Okay, I understand. You perhaps should have avoided the word "asymptotics" in your original question; as you can see, most of the people who responded got the wrong impression about your question. Anyway, I've added two expressions for your sum; neither involves a summation explicitly, but I'm not sure whether you would view them as closed form.

Comment: I thought you wrote sum(1/k!) from k=1 to N is $N!/(N-1)!$? I see now that you used incomplete gamma (the second answer is elegant if correct).